# Timeously downloading next TS segment in M3U8 file using Android's MediaPlayer classes

Tags: android, google-api, media-player, samsung-mobile

When playing an M3U8 file through MediaPlayer, the next TS segment is not being downloaded in time. On some devices (e.g. tablets) it does.
We think that it is [void PlaylistFetcher::onMonitorQueue()](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/httplive/PlaylistFetcher.cpp#593) which decides when to download the next TS segment. Is this method implemented in a different way on different devices?

We are developing for Android 4.0+